# Android plot demo app orientation sensor example history plot line thickness

Tags: androidplot

I have been unable to alter the plot line thickness for the History plot in the Orientation sensor Example (`OrientationSensorExampleActivity.java`)

None of the other queries about line thickness seem to be with the `FastLineAndPointRenderer`.

Is there an easy way to do this?

I need to make the plot lines thinner (a 100th of the overall height)

Thanks
Dean

Answer (score 1):

The thickness of all lines in Androidplot are controlled by an instance of Paint.  In the case of lines drawn by a Renderer (of any kind), it's the formatter that will contain the Paint instance.

Here's an example of setting the line thickness for a formatter used to draw a series with FastLineAndPointRenderer:

```
FastLineAndPointRenderer.Formatter formatter = new FastLineAndPointRenderer.Formatter(Color.RED, null, null);
formatter.getLinePaint().setStrokeWidth(PixelUtils.dpToPix(3));
plot.addSeries(azimuthHistorySeries, formatter);
```

Comment: Thanks very much Nick.I couldn't get it to work with my modified version of   the OrientationSensorExampleActivity.java file so i had a go adding it into the original. I used the following to get the three history plots :-          FastLineAndPointRenderer.Formatter formatter1 = new FastLineAndPointRenderer.Formatter(Color.rgb(100, 100, 200), null, null, null);
        formatter1.getLinePaint().setStrokeWidth(PixelUtils.dpToPix(1));
        aprHistoryPlot.addSeries(azimuthHistorySeries, formatter1);

Comment: FastLineAndPointRenderer.Formatter formatter2 = new FastLineAndPointRenderer.Formatter(Color.rgb(100, 200, 100), null, null, null);
        formatter2.getLinePaint().setStrokeWidth(PixelUtils.dpToPix(1));
        aprHistoryPlot.addSeries(pitchHistorySeries, formatter2);

Comment: FastLineAndPointRenderer.Formatter formatter3 = new FastLineAndPointRenderer.Formatter(Color.rgb(200, 100, 100), null, null, null);
        formatter3.getLinePaint().setStrokeWidth(PixelUtils.dpToPix(1));
        aprHistoryPlot.addSeries(rollHistorySeries, formatter3);

Comment: Interestingly when I reloaded the demo app  the history ploy line thickness was very narrow to start with. I am not sure why the lines were so much thicker on my modified version. I will do some backtracking to see what else is different.